# Hasura query action exception

Tags: docker, graphql, hasura

Got a small problem (I guess). I created c# rest web API on docker swarm environment. Rest API is working properly -  tested via the postman. Then I tried to compose Hasura service on the same docker swarm environment. The console is working properly also. The problem is with query action.

Code:

**Action definition**:

```
type Query {
  getWeatherForecast : [WeatherForecastResonse]
}
```

**New types definition**:

```
type WeatherForecastResonse {
  date : String
  temperatureC : Int
  temperature : Int
  summary : String
}
```

**Handler**:

```
http://{api ip}:{api port}/WeatherForecast
```

While trying to execute query:

```
query MyQuery {
  getWeatherForecast {
    temperature
    summary
    date
    temperatureC
  }
}
```

All I got from response is error with json:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "internal": {
          "error": "invalid json: Error in $: not enough input",
          "response": {
            "status": 405,
            "body": "",
            "headers": [
              {
                "value": "Mon, 14 Jun 2021 13:54:00 GMT",
                "name": "Date"
              },
              {
                "value": "Kestrel",
                "name": "Server"
              },
              {
                "value": "0",
                "name": "Content-Length"
              },
              {
                "value": "GET",
                "name": "Allow"
              }
            ]
          },
          "request": {
            "body": {
              "session_variables": {
                "x-hasura-role": "admin"
              },
              "input": {},
              "action": {
                "name": "getWeatherForecast"
              }
            },
            "url": "http://{api ip}:{api port}/WeatherForecast",
            "headers": []
          }
        },
        "path": "$",
        "code": "unexpected"
      },
      "message": "not a valid json response from webhook"
    }
  ]
}
```

I got desired response by using postman white calling: http://{api ip}:{api port}/WeatherForecast  (GET method)

Where should I improve, to finally get desired result from rest api?

P.S. hasura version: v2.0.0-alpha.4  (tried also with v1.3.3)

**UPDATE:**
Released a new version of web API. Inside WeatherForecastController included a new method with POST attribute. Query remained the same, but now graphql query returns what I want.

So the question is: **Is it possible to call/access web api methods with GET attribute with Hasura action query?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently it's not possible, Hasura always makes POST requests to the action handler:

> When the action is executed i.e. when the query or the mutation is called, Hasura makes a POST request to the handler with the action arguments and the session variables.

Source: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/actions/action-handlers.html#http-handler

Answer (score 2):

From the version v2.1.0 and above we can do this using the REST Connectors.[Hasura Actions RESTConnectors Methods](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/actions/rest-connectors.html#method)

> Go to the Actions tab on the console and create or modify an action. Scroll down to Configure REST Connectors.

> In the Configure REST Connectors section, click on Add Request Options Transform

Along with this you can do a lot of other configurations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31144516)